# Why $\int_0^{\pi } {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5}\;\mathrm{dt}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5}\;\mathrm{dt}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, periodic-functions, trigonometric-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

I can't figure out how this definite integral is transformed like this:

$$\int_0^{\pi } {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5} \;\mathrm{dt}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5} \;\mathrm{dt}$$

I've been studying the integration of even or periodic functions, but can't find anything useful about this particular example.
Any clue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a weird one all right!  I'm not sure what to do with the square roots in a symmetry argument here.

Comment: You can’t integrate the left-hand side. You have negative values for $t\in(\pi/2,\pi)$. The result becomes true if the range is instead $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: $\sin t$ is symmetrical across $t = \pi/2$. $\cos t$ is symmetrical across $t = 0$ or $t = \pi$

Comment: Perhaps its was supposed to be $|\cos t|$ rather than $(\cos t)$

Comment: @Clayton, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: So, what is the integral on the left really supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\int_0^{2a}f(x)\ dx=\int_0^af(x)\ dx+\int_a^{2a}f(x)\ dx$$

For the last integral, set $2a-x=y$

Can you recognise $f(x), a$ here?

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it: $\int_0^{\pi } {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5} \;\mathrm{dt}=\int_0^{2\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)} {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5} \;\mathrm{dt}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left(\cos \;t\right)}^{3\ldotp 5} \;\mathrm{dt}$